# Using Slack pipe in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: slack, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline and I want to use the slack pipe to send notification about the status of the execution of the pipeline, but the issue is that when putting the notification step at the end of the pipeline it doesn't get executed when the pipeline fails at earlier steps, so my question is how to make a certain step (slack step in this case) execute regardless of the earlier steps execution result?

After that I can use the BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE  variable to determine the pipeline execution status to send the appropriate notification status.
Or is there another clever way to use the slack pipe that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pipe in an `after-script` block instead of the regular main `script`. That is precisely intended for things like notifications and will run irrespective of what happened in the `script` block exposing the `BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE` variable you need.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#after-script

Comment: Thanks @N1ngu, I'm aware of that, but it requires to add an after-script block in each step while I wanted to have a single step that always runs regardless. Anyway, apparently that's the only way to go.